# How to remove connections between two nodes in TensorFlow model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, conv-neural-network

I have an RGB image and my first layer is a Convolution layer with kernel size (1x1) and depth of 3 (filters). Because the filter is 1x1, the size of the output image doesn't change. Looking at this pixel vice, we see 3 nodes of the image connected to 3 nodes of the layer. When I try to access weights, I get a [ 3x3 ] matrix.

I want to remove certain connections between nodes and want only certain connections to update their weights during training.

[image]

As shown in the image above, I want to remove all the connections displayed by the dotted lines.

I want weights to look something like this.

```
[[ some_value NA         NA        ],
 [ NA         some_value NA        ],
 [ NA         NA         some_value]]
```

How can I achieve this in TensorFlow model?

Following is the model architecture I'm working with.

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Conv2D(3, (1,1), input_shape = (256, 256, 3), activation = "relu"),
    keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (1,1), activation = "relu"),
    ])
```

Comment: I just recently answered this question before. Check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70387731/convolutional-layer-without-summation-over-different-channels-keras. What you essentially mean is to have each kernel only connects to one input channel. That is depthwise kernel and the operation is called depthwise convolution.

Comment: Even though the example I used shows only one-to-one connection, but the solution I'm expecting is where I can specify the connections I want to keep.

Comment: `Dropout` technique works by randomly reducing the number of interconnecting neurons within a neural network. At every training step, each neuron has a chance of being left out, or rather, dropped out of the collated contribution from connected neurons. Use `tf.keras.layers.Dropout` or more customised dropout layer `tf.keras.layers.AlphaDropout`, which keeps mean and variance of inputs to their original values. For more information https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dropout.

Comment: @TFer I want control over which connections are to be removed.

Comment: Dropout works at random level. AlphaDropout uses mean and variance value to drop neurons. If you want to drop specific neurons, You must try custom dropout layer. Thanks!